# Caffe make runtest error: BatchReindexLayerTest/3.TestGradient, where TypeParam = caffe::GPUDevice<double>

Tags: ubuntu, caffe, nvidia

I got this error when run  `sudo make runtest -j8` in caffe:

```
BatchReindexLayerTest/3.TestGradient, where TypeParam = caffe::GPUDevice<double>
```

[image]
My computer has two NVIDIA TITAIN XP devices and installed the NVIDIA driver linux-x86_64_387.26. The CUDA version is CUDA 9.1 with cuDNN for CUDA 9.1 and OpenCV 3.4.0. I had no compilation errors.

Comment: what version of caffe you are running? what branch? what local changes to source have you made? did you have any compilation errors when you built caffe? can you paste a more complete error message? what exactly is the error you got?

Comment: there's no cuDNN 9.1: there's cuDNN 7.0.5 for CUDA 9.1. do you mean this version?

Comment: Yes! I have forgotten the cuDNN version number  but it is the version corresponding to CUDN 9.1.

Answer (score 4):

This is a known issue with CUDA 9.1 and it seems independent from Caffe (meaning: the same code works flawlessly under previous releases of CUDA, but generates errors in v9.1). It is being tracked as issue [#6164](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/issues/6164).
Unless you plan to use BatchReindex layer, you shouldn't worry about it. Otherwise, consider downgrading to CUDA 9.0.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it is a common problem for CUDA 9.1. I tried to run mnist test and it didn’t have any error.So maybe the problem can be neglected.